# trying to filter specific words

Tags: python, list, filter

I started learning python 2 days ago, and I'm stuck

I have a list of 50 random colours

```
f = ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'orange', 'black', 'orange', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'purple', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'white', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'purple', 'red', 'orange', 'orange', 'blue', 'orange', 'black', 'red']
```

I would like to retrieve how many of one colour there is in the list, so I try and use filter and len

when I try and filter,

```
filter(lambda x:'red', f)
```

It returns back the full list so when I use len() it gives me 50.

Where am I going wrong with my filter? I have tried browsing through docs but can't seem to find anything but will keep looking.

Any tips?

My assignment spec states,

"(Excellent) Use map over the colours to count (using filter, and reduce or len) how often
each colour occurs in the result of subtask 3. Print the result."

Although count looks easier

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to filter all values which are `red`, using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x != 'red', f)
['black', 'blue', 'black', 'white', 'white', 'orange', 'black', 'orange', 'black
', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'purple', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'bla
ck', 'orange', 'white', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'ye
llow', 'blue', 'white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'white',
'black', 'purple', 'orange', 'orange', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in f if x != 'red']
```

Or a generator expression together with `list()`:

```
>>> list(x for x in f if x != 'red')
```

The issue you're having with

```
filter(lambda x:'red', f)
```

is that you're not comparing the elements of `f` with `'red'`. Essentially that function returns a new list with all of the elements from `f`. Any of the above methods will filter all `'red'` values from the list.

If you want to use this method to get the number of `'red'` elements (and not `list.count` which you should), then:

```
>>> len(filter(lambda x: x == 'red', f))
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda function isn't actually doing any comparison: it's just returning the string `'red'` each time, which is always True, so no items are being filtered out. You need to actually compare the string with the one that's being passed into the lambda, ie `x`:

```
filter(lambda x: x == 'red', f)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to retrieve how many of one colour there is in the list,

You don't have to filter, create a new list and then find the length of it. Simply use `list.count` function, like this

```
print f.count('red')
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you intentionally using `filter` and `lambda`?If you want to get the count of items, you can use the `count` method of the `list` type:

```
>>> f = ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'orange', 'black', 'orange', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'purple', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'white', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'purple', 'red', 'orange', 'orange', 'blue', 'orange', 'black', 'red']
>>> f.count("red")
8
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary would be the best for your case imho :)

f = ['black', 'blue', 'black', 'white', 'white', 'orange', 'black', 'orange', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'purple', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'white', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'white','black', 'purple', 'orange', 'orange', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']

```
dictionary = {}
for i in f:
    if i in dictionary:
        dictionary[i] += 1
    else:
        dictionary[i]  = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` is fine for one color but if you'd like to query multiple times:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> def get_as_count_dict(ls):
       res = defaultdict(int)
       for word in ls:
           res[word] += 1
       return res


>>> r = get_as_count_dict(['red', 'red', 'blue', 'pink'])
>>> r['red']
2

>>> r['nope']
0
```

Or we can use `Counter` directly:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> r = Counter(['red', 'red', 'blue', 'pink'])
>>> r['red']
2

>>> r['nope']
0
```

Comment: works brilliantly!, but don't want to just copy paste your answer will read docs